# How do I convert a list into a set without breaking down number?

Tags: python, set

I am trying to convert a list of times into a set so I can compare them to another set, but when I use

```
print(set(key))
```

it returns the set as `{'1', '7', ':', '0', ' '}`.

`key` originally contains this:

```
09:00
13:00
13:00
13:00
14:00
17:00
13:00
13:15
18:00
13:00
13:00
13:00
15:00
13:00
13:00
13:00
14:00
13:00
13:00
17:00
```

Is there a way to return the set so that it just contains `{'17:00'}` and is not broken down?

Comment: Why should it not contain 09:00 and 13:00 and 14:00 etc.?

Comment: "How do I convert a list..." - you don't *have* a list. Or what exactly is "key"? A string?

Comment: It looks like you're converting each element of the list to a set, instead of converting the list itself.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes sorry it should contain them all I just used 17:00 as an example

Comment: Please provide an [mre] showing how you're setting `key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### try the following code

set(key.split())

Answer (score 0):

if you have key values in list then print(set(key)) gives expected output.
like

```
key = ["9:00","13:00","13:00","15:00"]
print(set(key))
```

if key is string with whitespace seperating the time values
then

```
key = "9:00 13:00 13:00 15:00"
key_split = key.split(" ") #splits with spaces key.split() also works same as key.split(" ")
print(set(key_split))
```